# Loosing Nav Active State in Wordpress Dynamic Menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the following section:

http://www.zimmernutrition.com.php53-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/learning-center/

In the sidebar, if you click "Health Articles" and click one of the categories, the active "orange" state of "Learning Center" is lost. Articles are a custom post type and the categories are a related custom taxonomy.

Not sure if the menu is coded incorrectly, the CPT, the custom taxonomy or some combination.

Thanks for any help.

Brett

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record mine works. I'm using Chrome, but other browsers could well give issues.

I think that your CSS on the `current-menu-item`'s ect. just needs more pseudo types.

**Yours:**

```
#main-navigation .current-menu-item > a:link,
#main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a:link,
#main-navigation .current_page_item > a:link,
#main-navigation .current_page_parent > a:link,
#main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a:link {
  background: #e69433 url(images/template/nav-link-bg-over.jpg) left top repeat-x;
}

#main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
#main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
#main-navigation .current_page_parent > a,
#main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
  color: #000;
}
```

**I would combine them like so:** *(minus the extra classes)*

```
#main-navigation .current-menu-item a,
#main-navigation .current-menu-item a:link,
#main-navigation .current-menu-item a:visited,
#main-navigation .current-page-parent a,
#main-navigation .current-page-parent a:link,
#main-navigation .current-page-parent a:visited {
  background: #e69433 url(images/template/nav-link-bg-over.jpg) left top repeat-x;
  color: #000;
}

#main-navigation .current-menu-item a:hover,
#main-navigation .current-menu-item a:active,
#main-navigation .current-page-parent a:hover,
#main-navigation .current-page-parent a:active {
  background: orange url(images/template/nav-link-bg-over.jpg) left top repeat-x;
  color: pink;
}
```

Also the `>` is something that non modern browsers won't understand. Might be safer to remove it completely.

**- UPDATE -**

Looking closer at the list items on both the parent and the child page, this is what you have:

*Parent Item*
`<li id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-15 current_page_item menu-item-142">`

*Child Page*
`<li id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-142">`

**I've adjusted** the styles above to match the necessary classes.

Comment: This doesn't work.  WP doesn't (at least not in my case) apply a .current-menu-item to all levels up/down the tree.  What's with the pink color?

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not this is a browser specific problem? Did you just copy my code or actually extend it to match all the classes you originally included (which I've edited in now). Pink is just there to confirm the hovers work, not because me thinks it's beautiful. :)